# customer_visitor magento 2.1.5 errors : 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: magento2, customer

I am getting below error every nigth at 00:00. Problem with clean customer visitor. How i can

```
a:4:{i:0;s:198:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `customer_visitor` (`customer_id`, `session_id`, `last_visit_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";i:1;s:12982:"#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
```

How can I cleaning up customer_visitor table log. is it creates any problems if cleaning up this table

Answer (score 0):

There is a cronjob to clean the `customer_visitor` table.

`vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/crontab.xml`

```
<group id="default">
    <job name="visitor_clean" instance="Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor" method="clean">
        <schedule>0 0 * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

This cronjob will run at middle night `At 00:00`. So, multi-operations can cause the locks here.

My suggestions:

1) Check your server capacity (RAM, CPU, Hard Driver)

2) As I see, this part can cause database stress if the site has a huge concurrent visitors.

If we're using other tools(Google Analytics, etc..) to track the website, I think we can disable those events. That will reduce the extra load to the database.

For example:

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="customer_visitor" disabled="true" />
</event>
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch">
    <observer name="customer_visitor" disabled="true" />
</event>
```